# Using aspnet core, data-countdown.js adding time with Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I Make a model with a Datetime, like an alarm, a time remain to . With a button that delay the time in 60 seconds

[image]

The model, view and controller to make this work:

```
public class WakeMe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeToWake { get; set; }
    public string? User { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
DateTime itsNow = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan timeLeft = itsNow - horaInicio;
int intTimeLeft = Convert.ToInt32(timeLeft.TotalMilliseconds);
intTimeLeft = Math.Abs(intTimeLeft);
```

I put the time in milliseconds for JavaScript to count down through the .remain class

//The View

```
 <div class="card-header">Wake me in em @Model.DataHoraInicio</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6" id="principal">

                    @if (Model.TimeToWake > DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        DateTime Agora = DateTime.Now;

                        TimeSpan tempoRestante = Agora - Model.DataHoraInicio;
                        int intTempoRestante = Convert.ToInt32(tempoRestante.TotalMilliseconds);
                        intTempoRestante = Math.Abs(intTempoRestante);


                        <div class="" id="@intTempoRestante">
                            <span class="remain text-dark"></span>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="id" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="60" name="intValor" />
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn">let me sleep for more 60 secs.</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

@section Scripts{
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
        $('div[id]').each(function () {
            var obj = $(this);
            var diff = parseInt(obj.attr("id"));
            var countdown = setInterval(function () {
                diff = diff - 1000;
                var h = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
                var m = Math.floor((diff - (h * 3600000)) / 60000);
                var s = Math.floor((diff - (h * 3600000) - (m * 60000)) / 1000);


                if (m < 10) {
                    m = '0' + m;
                } else {
                    m = m + '';
                }

                if (s < 10) {
                    s = '0' + s;
                } else {
                    s = s + '';
                }



                var goodDate = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
                $('.remain', obj).html(goodDate);
            }, 1000);
        });


        $('#btn').click(function () {
            var div = $('#principal').html();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/testedois',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: 1, segundos: 60 },
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    if (data.success == 'ok') {
                        $(' #principal').html(div);
                    } else {
                        // show errors.
                    }
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("error");
                })
                .always(function () {
                    console.log("complete");
                });
        });
    });</script>
}
```

### WHAT HAPPENS

Clicking the button makes the Ajax call and adds the requested time. But on the counter it doesn't add the added time.

What could I do besides updating the database, updating the div, or the form itself?

### Page Example

The page working [here](https://test.kondotec.com.br/)

Comment: I link you have shared has no activity and remain freeze as well. So could you please let us know your expected result?

Comment: Thanks for advice. When I Click the button he adds 60 seconds from Ajax call, but the result just appears if reload the page. I wanted to update at click time, by ajax, which is not working.